# Adding anaconda to PATH

Tags: python, path, anaconda

I downloaded both Anaconda 2 and 3 and added them to my PATH, but when I open a new terminal and check the anaconda version, my computer says command not found: conda. I have added the commands to show what I am experiencing.

```
# added by Anaconda2 5.2.0 installer
export PATH="/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
➜  ~ export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
➜  ~ export PATH="/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"

➜  ~ conda --version
zsh: command not found: conda
➜  ~ ports -v
zsh: command not found: ports
➜  ~
```

Comment: I am also having the same issue with MacPorts

Comment: Have you looked in those directories to see if there is "conda" executable (of any kind) present? What does `which conda` output? If there are other environment that needs the changed path you might have to "rehash" as well.

Comment: yea there is a conda exe in both directories..

Comment: I just don't want to have to keep adding it to the path every time I want to use it.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your example shows your (unknown) shell on your (unknown) platform failing to find two executables when added to your PATH environment. Now you are implying it does work for you, but you have some other problem. Which is it? You can [edit] your question and clarify, but the fact is that this question is probably off topic if it is about getting executables to be found on your PATH for some platform/shell combination.

Comment: If MacPorts is also failing for you, then this might be better researched over on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). SO is about coding questions, and this seems to be about getting executables to be found via the shell.

Comment: I am running terminal on Mac OS and my problem is simply that I don't want to add my conda to PATH every time I load shell.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this makes no sense. If you want a directory of executables to be found on the PATH, you have to add this directory to the PATH. Unless you mean you don't want to have to invoke an executable with an _absolute_ path? i.e., `/some/path/to/anaconda2/conda' vs. 'conda'? Or maybe you mean you want to have the shell have these executables on the PATH whenever you start the shell? You should be clearer about what problem you want to solve. Either way, though, this is off-topic for SO.